# Applescript: return specific index positions from a date string

Tags: date, applescript, offset

I have already used the text delimiters and item numbers to extract a date from a file name, so I'm clear about how to use these. Unfortunately the date on these particular files are formatted as "yyyyMMdd" and I need to covert the date into format "yyyy-MM-dd". I have been trying to use the offset function to get particular index positions, and I have found several examples of how you would return the offset of particular digits in the string, example:

```
set theposition to offset of 10 in theString -- this works
```

(which could return 5 or 7) but I have not found examples of how to call the digits at a specific index:

```
set _day to offset 7 of file_date_raw -- error 

         "Finder got an error: Some parameter is missing for offset." number -1701
```

How would you do this, or is there a totally better way I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "call the digits at a specific index", you use:

```
text 1 thru 4 of myString
```

If you know that each string has 8 characters in the yyyymmdd format, then you don't need to use 'offset' or any parsing, just add in the -'s, using text x thru y to dissect the string.

```
set d to "20011018"
set newString to (text 1 thru 4 of d) & "-" & (text 5 thru 6 of d) & "-" & (text 7 thru 8 of d)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!